# Nested query results mapped to Java data types

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I have two tables in my Sybase database A and B. The relationship between them is one-to-many where an entry in A may have one or more entries in B associated with it (via ID).

I am trying to replicate this relationship in Java code, where I'd have a data structure for an entry in table A that would contain a list of entries from table B associated with it. Is there a way to create some sort of mapper in Spring where I can avoid loading two result sets and then trying to consolidate them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Look, for example, at MyBatis mapper (Advanced Result Mapping section in http://mybatis.googlecode.com/files/MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf). 
You can load you one-to-many structure in the single query, and of course you can integrate mybatis mapping in your spring application context.

I suppose you can get the same result with any ORM tool.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to use the `SimpleJdbcTemplate` from Spring and its `RowMapper`s to avoid any more 3rd party tools. I'll keep this in mind though!